# Parsing Decoded JSON in PHP (blokchain API)

Tags: php, json, bitcoin, blockchain, blockchain.info-api

Hello I am trying to extract some info from a json format page

The page is : https://blockchain.info/fr/rawaddr/1BQLNJtMDKmMZ4PyqVFfRuBNvoGhjigBKF

this link allows to get all bitcoin transactions from an address.
All the quotation marks confuse me, I can not see clearly

I want to display everything like the original blockchain website
[Blockchain Display view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaMUJ.png)
The beginning will be something like that

```
$json = file_get_contents("https://blockchain.info/fr/rawaddr/1BQLNJtMDKmMZ4PyqVFfRuBNvoGhjigBKF");
var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

I can extract basic info from JSO to php, but here there is too much transactions and I think we need to use a loop to display everything but I don't know how to do that
If someone can display for me in php the 5 first transactions it will be very sympathic.

Thanks a lot in advance youw ill really help me if you can do that !

Comment: Show what you've tried.  SO is not a "Write this for me" service.

Comment: This is how you use a foreach loop in PHP: `for($arr as $a){//your code here}`

Comment: I know that I have to use a foreach loop but in which way ? I don't know exactly, if you can provide me an exemple or the beginning I'll be able to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you goal is to display all Tx info you want to do that.

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://blockchain.info/fr/rawaddr/1BQLNJtMDKmMZ4PyqVFfRuBNvoGhjigBKF");
$txs = json_decode($json,1)['txs'];
echo"<pre>"; //just to get a human readable display
foreach($txs as $txinfo){
    echo"A new tx";
    //will display the full tx data
    print_r($txinfo);
}

echo"</pre>";
```

Note a blockchain transaction can be a little complexe since one transaction can have multiple input and multiple outputs.
you might want to cycle trough outputs as well to display all addresses who received bitcoin from a transaction
in that case you can simply add another foreach output

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://blockchain.info/fr/rawaddr/1BQLNJtMDKmMZ4PyqVFfRuBNvoGhjigBKF");
$txs = json_decode($json,1)['txs'];
echo"<pre>"; //just to get a human readable display
foreach($txs as $txinfo){
    echo"A new tx";
    //will display the full tx data
    print_r($txinfo);
    // will cycle trough all output for each tx
    foreach ($txinfo['out'] as $outgoingTransaction)
    {
        //Will display the receiving address
       $receivingAddress = $outgoingTransaction['addr'];
       //will get the amount sent in satoshis
       $receivingAmountInSatoshi = $outgoingTransaction['value'];

       echo"<br>1BQLNJtMDKmMZ4PyqVFfRuBNvoGhjigBKF sent to $receivingAddress  $receivingAmountInSatoshi satoshis <br>";

    }

}
```

a more advanced code to add tx understanding logic

```
$walletAddress = '1AWKFrvFYuCC7ef2m2zX73pWu1C15FRGjR' ;
$json = file_get_contents("http://blockchain.info/fr/rawaddr/$walletAddress");
$txs = json_decode($json,1)['txs'];
echo"<pre>"; //just to get a human readable display

foreach($txs as $txinfo){

    $spendingTx = false ;
    $totalSpent = 0 ;
    $totalReceived = 0;

    echo"<p>Txid = $txinfo[hash]<br>";
    //print_r($txinfo);

    // we need to find out if the address is the sender or the receiver
    $senderData = reset($txinfo['inputs']); //using reset to get only the first input
    if ($senderData['prev_out']['addr'] ==$walletAddress ){
        //the address is the sender meaning the address is spending
        $spendingTx = true ;

    }

   //it's a spend tx then we cycle trough receivers
    if ($spendingTx) {

        foreach ($txinfo['out'] as $outgoingTransaction) {
            //Will display the receiving address
            $receivingAddress = $outgoingTransaction['addr'];
            //will get the amount sent in satoshis
            $receivingAmountInSatoshi = $outgoingTransaction['value'];
            $totalSpent = $totalSpent + $receivingAmountInSatoshi ;
            echo "<br>$walletAddress sent to $receivingAddress  $receivingAmountInSatoshi satoshis <br>";

        }

        echo "<br>Total spent = $totalSpent" ;

    }
        //it is not a spending tx so it's a receceiving tx
        else {

            foreach ($txinfo['out'] as $outgoingTransaction) {

                //We keep only receiving data concerning current wallet
                if ($outgoingTransaction['addr'] == $walletAddress) {
                    //Will display the receiving address
                    $receivingAddress = $outgoingTransaction['addr'];
                    //will get the amount sent in satoshis
                    $receivingAmountInSatoshi = $outgoingTransaction['value'];
                    $senderAddress = $senderData['prev_out']['addr'];
                    $totalReceived = $receivingAmountInSatoshi;
                    echo "<br>$walletAddress received $receivingAmountInSatoshi satoshis from $senderAddress<br>";

                }

            }
            echo "<br>Total received = $totalReceived" ;

        }

        echo"<br>end tx </p>";
}

echo"</pre>";
```

Comment: I will use a simple address with only 2 transactions, 1 in and 1 out
1AWKFrvFYuCC7ef2m2zX73pWu1C15FRGjR
So the link will become $json = file_get_contents("http://blockchain.info/fr/rawaddr/1AWKFrvFYuCC7ef2m2zX73pWu1C15FRGjR");

Your code is very legit, but I don't want to only display outpout transactions I want to display all transactions.

Like this : https://image.prntscr.com/image/DU72DTBkQWKPS47Vuim_Lw.png
Excactly the same

but when I try your code there is only sent transactionsfrom the original address who works
I try this but it dosen't works http://prntscr.com/ft5l3n

Comment: In that case you need a bit more advanced PHP array parsing in order to go get the data you you want. I'm updating the response to get more advanced data.

Comment: You are a monster ! thanks a lot man, I understood how it works. It's just the logic